# Prioritize PC with same host names

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I have two computers (desktop & laptop), where the laptop needs to access a drive on the desktop (for backups etc.). My current solution is as follows:

- I have OpenVPN network with the desktop as the server and the laptop as the client
- The laptop tries to access the desktop via its name (i.e. `\\Lukas-PC\share\...`)

  - If both PCs are at home, this causes the laptop to connect to the desktop directly, which is of course faster
  - If I am not at home, the laptop finds the desktop in the VPN, and accesses it that way.

So far, this has been working without issues. Recently however, a PC with the same name than my desktop has appeared in the network of my university, and is advertised by the DNS server there (e.g. `ping Lukas-PC` pings that PC instead). This means that now, my laptop can't perform the backup anymore, since it finds the wrong computer.

I could of course change the name of the PC, but that seems like a temporary fix until some PC has the same name again. I could also use the IP of the PC to connect to it, but then I loose the performance advantage at home.

How can I solve this, e.g. by forcing windows to not look for `\\Lukas-PC\` in a specific network?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you assign named entry in hosts file so whenever you try to connect with Lukas-PC it will check it's entry in the hosts file and found the system's IP address & ultimately connect to that

location of hosts file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\
```

edit the hosts file (preferable with notepad++)

```
192.168.x.x Lukas-PC
```

or you can provide other names as well

```
192.168.x.x Lukas-PC Lukas-PC123 LukasPC.example.com
```

so whenever you try to access the Desktop from above names it will ultimately redirected to that IP

Comment: How can I achieve the "fallback" mechanism with this? I.e. it should try the home network IP first, and fall back to the VPN IP if the first one fails